# Read string from text file and save it to a variable to be used in a bash script

Tags: bash, scripts

I have a text file containing a string (`file_id.txt`). In my bash script, I'm trying to read this string and save it to a variable. This variable has to be used in a python file which opens a viewer in the terminal (using curses library).

My bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
file_path="/home/io/path/to/file/file_id.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
    file_id=$line
    python mpeg_g_tools_MG.py -in /home/io/another/path/$file_id.txt 

done < "$file_path"
```

This script correctly pass the string to the python file, but, as soon as the viewer is opened, it closes because of the while loop.

If I launch the viewer outside the loop, variable file_id is empty.

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    file_id=$line        
done < "$file_path"         
python mpeg_g_tools_MG.py -in /home/io/another/path/$file_id.txt
```

Any help would be very appreciated!

EDIT 1: `file_id.txt` content:

```
c88-90ijh-iuguk-uuuuhhg-7ytf
```

Comment: If you're just reading a single line you don't need a loop at all, surely? You could just do `IFS= read -r line < "$file_path"`. Having said that, I don't see why using a loop should cause the viewer to close - the shell shouldn't even try to read another line until the python program terminates. Unless your python program is forking itself into the background?

Comment: ... or even just `file_id=$(<"$file_path")` if you don't care about leading whitespace

Comment: @steeldriver thank you, I edited the code using `file_id=$(<"$file_path")` and it worked. If you make an answer from it, I will accept it.